# How to integrate maven generated vaadin project into eclipse vaadin plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin

Eclipse Vaadin plugin has cool autobuild feature. Just clicking "restart application" in debug console will bring up to date application version to live.

Unfortunately  importing maven generated vaadin project(using m2e) and copy-pasting .project buildCommands and natures from vaadin eclipse plugin generated project does not works.

I'm unnable to "Run on server...", tomcat does not deploy app for unknown reason. I can see app in wtpapps folder but it still does not deploys.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything. Are you using M2Eclipse? Are you using the maven-eclipse-plugin? Both? Can you clarify the exact steps to reproduce? Also, what are the requirements? What additionalProjectnatures do you need? What buildCommands do you need? Can you show your maven-eclipse-plugin configuration (if I'm following you)?

Comment: I'm using m2eclipse, importing project generated like this:
"mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST -DgroupId=com.example  -DartifactId=MyWebUI -Dversion=0.1 -Dpackaging=war"

I need to add WTP nature to have "Run on server..." command. And Vaadin for on the fly updating app without any maven builds.

To achive this i just copy-pasted .project contents from project generated by vaadin eclipse plugin which works perfectly. But "Run on server..." fails to deploy app, tomcat cant see it giving 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your Vaadin app as a regular Java library, by itself (not as a WAR, or anything complicated). Then do two things: Create another project that builds the actual WAR file, and create another project that sets up Jetty for direct execution (google for details on how to get Vaadin operating under Jetty standalone, using Jetty as a library). With that in place you can treat your Vaadin UI like a regular java program (fast, direct restart through the standard debug window), and still have it be a WAR file for deployment.

See [this thread](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/17934) for details on how to set up Jetty (look for Launcher).

Comment: hehe, i waited for this respone a little bit more then a year 8)

Comment: I am doing that, but it seems that this way, you are still lacking some features, such as "Rebuild widgetset" which is necessary for some Vaadin Addons to work.

Comment: I find that I sometimes have to trigger a maven build on the project to get the widgetset rebuilt. I don't have to do it very often, but it does happen, usually on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have also stumbled upon this problem some time ago and eventually found this:

http://www.streamhead.com/maven-spring-vaadin-appengine/

It eventually helped me to get up and running after a scenario that has been very similar to what you have described.